# SQL Update Statement with a Case with Select Inside

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to run a mass update statement that selects the min and max of a column. The issue is that there are multiple columns with null values. If `NULL` then I want to set the `MinValue` to `0`.

I have the following statement, but I am getting errors with the `SELECT` and `ELSE`:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET MaxValue = (
        SELECT MAX(column1) FROM Table2), 
        MinValue = (CASE 
            WHEN SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2 <> NULL 
            THEN SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2 
            ELSE '0' 
        END)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't compare to NULL in that manner and I'm fairly sure that MIN will ignore NULLs unless there's no other options... not the reason for your error but you will have problems. CASE is designed to have the same datatype, so by turning 0 into a string you may also hurt yourself.

Comment: Does Table1 have any relationship with Table2?

Comment: Did you try to put parentheses around the subqueries in the case like this: `WHEN (SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2) <> NULL`

Comment: Please don't taunt us by saying that you are getting errors, but that you won't share them. Do you really want to update _all_ rows, i.e. no WHERE clause, with the _same_ MinValue and MaxValue, i.e. no correlation of the subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some immediately obvious adjustments that you need to make:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET MaxValue = (
       SELECT MAX(column1) FROM Table2),
       MinValue = (CASE
           WHEN (SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2) IS NOT NULL -- subquery in parentheses per John Gibb's comment and IS NOT NULL rather than <> NULL
           THEN (SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2) -- subquery in parentheses per John Gibb's comment
           ELSE 0 -- 0 rather than '0'
       END)
```

Otherwise, you are effectively coalescing with a `CASE`: I would use `COALESCE` instead.

Comment: I still don't think that'll work without parentheses

Comment: Thanks, @JohnGibb.  Good catch.  I updated the answer to reflect that additional adjustment.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
UPDATE a
SET    a.MaxValue = b.max_val,
       a.MinValue = COALESCE(b.min_val, 0)
FROM   Table1 a
       CROSS JOIN 
       (
          SELECT MAX(column1) max_val, 
                 MIN(column1) min_val 
          FROM   Table2
       ) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
UPDATE Table1 SET MaxValue = (SELECT MAX(column1) FROM Table2), 
                 MinValue = COALESCE( SELECT MIN(column1) FROM Table2, '0' )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does table1 only hold 1 row? How come you need a table for that? Have you considered using a view?

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(column1),0) AS MaxValue,
  COALESCE(MIN(column1),0) AS MinValue
FROM dbo.Table2
```

Also, why not coalesce the max as well.. just in case.

If you must use a table...

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1
SET MinValue = t.[min],
  MaxValue = t.[max]
FROM (SELECT MIN(column1) [min], MAX(column1) [max] FROM dbo.Table2) t
```